# How many Watts is my LG Refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

Please I want to find out the watt of my LG Table Top Refrigerator ..I lost the manuals [image: This is what I found pasted on the body]

Comment: The good news: LG has plenty of information - just search for **GC-051SQ** and you'll get there. The bad news - the Owner's Manual doesn't say anything about power and the Specs on the web site only say **Energy Consumption (kWh/year) 106**. If you are looking for *approximate* total power usage, that works. But it is an average based on typical usage and does not tell you the actual Watts used when the compressor is running, etc.

Comment: Have you tried contacting LG?

Comment: There has to be another label where the power connects to the unit that says what it will draw.

Comment: I smell an XY problem. What is the purpose of your inquiry?